# Search field under SE dropdown seems broken on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

Something seems amiss on [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), where typing in the "Find a Stack Exchange Community" search field under the Stack Exchange dropdown does nothing. There is also some strange overlap going on with the magnifying glass and the type.

[image: Red freehand circle emphasizing broken feature]

Comment: No repro Firefox 90.0 64bit on win 10, nor Version 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit) on win 10.

Comment: Able to reproduce, as you point out, *only* on chat sites, not main sites.

Comment: Chrome 91.0.4472.114 Win 10 and not working on my mobile either

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes it's strictly from chat.stackexchange.com as mentioned in the question (which is probably why it hadn't been noticed)

Comment: Repro'd on chrome on android as well.

Comment: My above comment, the 91 bit should have said Chrome 91.0.4472.124, sorry.

Comment: Note that chat uses the entirely old-style top bar and was never updated when everything else was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On the JS issue**

It seems like there is a discrepancy between the page JavaScript and the markup. If one inspects the `main.js` file served, they will find that it uses a `typeWatch` [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) to initialize the search input during the `afterLoad` lifecycle hook.

The problem is that the script expects to find an element matching a `#js-site-filter-txt` (id selector) whereas the search input only has a *class* `js-site-filter-txt` set which means that the correct selector should've been `.js-site-filter-txt`.

And indeed, if you have a userscript manager or use [local overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides) to override the file, the search starts working as expected:

[image: search input fixed with local overrides]

If you want to fix it in the script file, here is the block you need to look for (alternatively, you can add the id to the input, but be aware that the dialog is loaded via an AJAX request for a server rendered HTML):

```js
"afterLoad": function() {
                   //  problem #1
  this.$dialog.find("#js-site-filter-txt").typeWatch({
      "highlight": !1,
      "wait": 250,
      "captureLength": -1,
      "callback": $.proxy(this.filterSites, this)
    }),
    this.$searchItems = this.$dialog.find(".js-other-sites li").clone().map(function() {
      return {
        "title": $(".site-icon", this).attr("title").toLowerCase(),
        "description": $(".site-desc", this).text().toLowerCase(),
        "hostname": $("a", this).first().attr("href"),
        "li": this
      }
    });
  var e = this.$dialog;
                    //  problem #2
  this.$dialog.find("#js-site-filter-txt").focus(function() {
      var t = e.offset().top + e.height(),
        n = e.find(".other-sites li:nth-child(2)"),
        i = n.offset().top + n.height();
      i > t && e.animate({
        "scrollTop": e.scrollTop() + i - t
      }, 750)
    }),
    this.supr()
},
```

Here is a miniature userscript for fixing the broken input on the fly (both the JavaScript and CSS part [see below on the latter]):

[Install URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/userscripters/chat-search-fixup/master/dist/modern/index.js) [Repository](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-search-fixup)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @author          Oleg Valter
// @description     Fix chat search input without having to wait 6 to 8 weeks
// @grant           none
// @homepage        https://github.com/userscripters/chat-search-fixup#readme
// @match           https://chat.stackexchange.com
// @match           https://chat.stackoverflow.com
// @name            chat-search-fixup
// @namespace       userscripters
// @source          git+https://github.com/userscripters/chat-search-fixup.git
// @supportURL      https://github.com/userscripters/chat-search-fixup/issues
// @version         1.0.0
// ==/UserScript==

(function(w, d) {
    'use strict';

    const searchClass = "js-site-filter-txt";

    w.addEventListener("load", () => {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            converters: {
                "text html": (data) => data.replace(
                    new RegExp(`(<input)(.+class=".*?)\s?${searchClass}`, "g"),
                    `$1 id="${searchClass}"$2`
                )
            }
        });
    });

    const style = d.createElement("style");
    d.head.append(style);
    const { sheet } = style;
    if(!sheet) return;

    [
        `.s-input.s-input__search,
         .s-input.s-input__creditcard {
           padding-left: 32px !important;
           box-sizing: border-box;
        }`
    ].forEach((rule) => sheet.insertRule(rule));

})(window, document);
```

---

**On the CSS issue**

The search icon is an SVG element with the `position` rule set to `absolute` via the `.s-input-icon` ruleset. That's how it is supposed to be in the [new design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/inputs/#search). What is amiss here, however, is a `padding-left` rule that would shift the `placeholder` attribute. The ruleset from the Stacks design is as follows:

```css
.s-input.s-input__creditcard, 
.s-input.s-input__search {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
```

The above ruleset is also present in the stylesheet served by chat.* subdomain, except that the `padding-left` rule is overridden with a `padding` rule from a ruleset with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```css
.topbar input[type="text"] {
    transition: none;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: var(--ff-sans);
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 3px; // our culprit
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

But before fixing the issue, one has to address another problem. If one is to add an inline `padding-left` override, they will observe the input sticking out (overflowing) the modal on the right:

[image: input overflowing the modal right side]

This is due to the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule being set to `content-box` which only includes the content dimensions (margins, padding, and borders are, therefore, excluded). Changing the rule to `border-box` gives us the desired result:

[image: input with the fixed border-box rule]

Since `border-box` is the default (and normally unchanged) rule value, where does it come from? It turns out that the stylesheet has the following ruleset applied to the `<body>` element propagating down to the search input:

```css
body {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Give it 6 to 8 weeks. In the meantime, you can force the rule with `!important` (dirty, but it's not like Stacks don't use it too) and add a rule overriding the inherited `box-sizing`:

```css
.s-input.s-input__search, .s-input.s-input__creditcard {
    padding-left: 32px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And voila (add width/margin adjustments to your taste):

[image: search input with overrides applied]